# How to make the Value in the inputText dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I m trying to make the default value for the input field from an array in the state..i could 
 put the values but after that i am not able to change the field any more ( it works wrong i can add only one letter which is strange ) 
(PS: there is only one input in my code ) :

when i change the value="" in the input it works but i need this table to contain the values from the state.

```
        state ={

        splitAmount : [ {

        SplitAmount0: this.props.data.amount1
          },
         {
        SplitAmount1: this.props.data.amount2
         },
       {
        SplitAmount2: this.props.data.amount3
      }
      ],  
    }

  }


 StopTyping = (event) => {
    const self = this;
    if (self.state.typingTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(self.state.typingTimeout);
    }
    self.setState({
        val : event.target.value,
        name : event.target.name,
        id : event.target.id,
        typingTimeout: setTimeout(function () {
            self.setAmount(self.state.name,self.state.id,self.state.val);
        }, 1000)
    });


}
setAmount=(name,id,val)=>{
    this.removeSplitAmount(name);
    let some=0;
    for(var i=0;i<this.state.splitAmount.length;i++){
        let splitAmountState=`SplitAmount${i}`;
        some+=this.state.splitAmount[i][splitAmountState]
    }
    let newAmount=this.props.data.amount-(some+val);

    if(some>0){

        let newValues=[{[val]:val},{[`SplitAmount${id+1}`]:newAmount}]
        let newSplitAmount=this.state.splitAmount.concat(newValues);
        this.setState({splitAmount:newSplitAmount})

    }
}


      return(
               <div>
                {this.state.splitAmount.map((splitAmount,i)=>{
                    const splitAmountKey=i
                    return(
                        <table className="middle-table"key={i}>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>DueDate</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>VAT</th>
                                <th>Otherexpenses</th>
                                <th>SocialSecurity</th>
                                <th>Miscelaneous</th>
                                <th>TaxableAmount</th>
                            </tr>
                  <tr style={{height:40}}>
                           <td className="middle-table- 
        col">05.12.2018</td>
                           <td className="middle-table-colright-align"> 
                     {this.props.data.status}</td>
                            <td className="middle-table-colright-align">
                             <input className="tax-value" value= 
           {this.state.splitAmount[i][`SplitAmount ${i}`]} id={i} name= 
              {'SplitAmount'+i}
                                                               onChange= 
                      {this.StopTyping}/>
                            </td>
                  <td className="middle-table-colright-align"> 
                    {this.props.data.vatAmount}</td>
                <td className="middle-table-colright-align"> 
               {this.props.data.otherExpenses}</td>
                <td className="middle-table-colright-align"> 
                  {this.props.data.socialSecurityAmountIncluded}</td>
                  <td className="middle-table-colright-align"> 
              {this.props.data.miscellaneousDeduction}</td>
                 <td className="middle-table-colright- 
                     align"style={{backgroundColor:'#F4F6F8'}}>1000</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    )
                })}
```

Comment: Your `StopTyping` method sounds suspicious. Please add the code of that implementation. Pretty sure that we find the issue there. I'd expect that you pass `i` to that method to update the correct value in your complex state.

Comment: done @Andreas_D ..may be this  {this.state.splitAmount[i][`SplitAmount ${i}`]} is weired ..but for s the only way to initialize the table from the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update state, never use the current state array or object: we always have to create a new structure and update the state with that. So, in your 'StopTyping' method (which should be renamed to 'taxValueChangeHandler', really!), say:

```
let newSplitAmount=[...this.state.splitAmount].concat(newValues);
```

It creates a new array with all values of splitAmount and concatenates that with the new values.

Then, in the input element, I'd always explicitly pass the event, if the event is needed in the method:

```
onChange={(e) => StopTyping(e)}
```

Hope this already helps!